# How to change the font size of the list column titles

Tags: sharepoint-online

Long time ago I have changed the font size of the list column titles. But
i forgot to document it. Now I don't know how i did that ! And i can find the css code either !!!

Greetings,
P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please note that modern SharePoint does not support custom CSS via AlternateCSSUrl web property, and also modifying master page is not supported either.

See the reference here to see what is supported for customization in modern SharePoint: [Customizing "modern" lists and libraries.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/modern-experience-customizations-customize-lists-and-libraries)

You can apply the following CSS to classic experience in SharePoint Online:

```
<style>

/*Choose your background color*/
.ms-viewheadertr{
    background:#00426A;
}

/*Choose font style*/
.ms-vh2-nofilter, .ms-vh2, a.ms-headerSortTitleLink {
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    font-size:1.05em;
}
</style>
```

Reference:

[SharePoint Online: Increase the Column Header Font and Change Header font color in SharePoint List.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d0bf70fe-8836-46c0-adeb-058c74669c71/sharepoint-online-increase-the-column-header-font-and-change-header-font-color-in-sharepoint-list?forum=sharepointdevelopment)

[Customize styles/formatting of SharePoint list column header rows.](https://natechamberlain.com/2018/07/20/customize-styles-formatting-of-sharepoint-list-column-header-rows/)